# creating std::functional object to wrap a lambda with a call to static member function

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

**EDIT** Code I was talkin about here is available on my Github. https://github.com/SP8EBC/ParaGADACZ/blob/master/src/PlaylistAssembler.cpp . Lines between 103 and 110

---

I try to make a wrapper around `value_of` method from `std::optional` in c++17. An idea is to throw an exception if optional doesn't hold any object, and to keep code clean not to write explicit ifs.

I came up with such construction

```
    std::function<std::string()> lazyFailsafe = [=]() {PlaylistAssembler::throwOnEmptyOptional();};

    // add current weather anouncement
    playlist->push_back(playlistSampler
            .getConstantElement(PlaylistSampler_ConstanElement::CURRENT_WEATHER)
            .value_or(lazyFailsafe));
```

The problem is that regardless if i will capture `this` or `=` or anything else it never compiles. GCC always returns an error message like that

> ../src/PlaylistAssembler.cpp: In member function ‘void
> PlaylistAssembler::currentWeather(std::vectorstd::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> org::openapitools::client::model::Summary> >&,
> std::vector&)’: ../src/PlaylistAssembler.cpp:103:105:
> error: conversion from
> ‘PlaylistAssembler::currentWeather(std::vectorstd::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> org::openapitools::client::model::Summary> >&,
> std::vector&)::<lambda()>’ to non-scalar type
> ‘std::functionstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char()>’ requested   103 |
> std::functionstd::string() lazyFailsafe = this
> {PlaylistAssembler::throwOnEmptyOptional();};
> |

Worth mentioning is that `PlaylistAssembler::throwOnEmptyOptional();` is of course a static class member. How should I create and use such object?

***EDIT***
After a hint given by @UnholySheep i added missing return and now this snipped looks like that

````
> std::function<std::string()> lazyFailsafe = [=]()
> {PlaylistAssembler::throwOnEmptyOptional(); return std::string();};
> 
> // add current weather anouncement playlist->push_back(playlistSampler
>       .getConstantElement(PlaylistSampler_ConstanElement::CURRENT_WEATHER)
>       .value_or(lazyFailsafe));
> 
> ``` Unfortunately I still have compile errors related to this
> value_or. Printout is very, very long but it begins with
> 
> In file included from ../src/PlaylistSampler.h:13,
>                  from ../src/PlaylistAssembler.h:17,
>                  from ../src/PlaylistAssembler.cpp:8: /usr/include/c++/11/optional: In instantiation of ‘constexpr _Tp
> std::optional<_Tp>::value_or(_Up&&) && [with _Up =
> std::function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>()>&; _Tp =
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
> ../src/PlaylistAssembler.cpp:108:13:   required from here
> /usr/include/c++/11/optional:997:25: error: static assertion failed  
> 997 |           static_assert(is_convertible_v<_Up&&, _Tp>);
>       |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/11/optional:997:25: note:
> ‘std::is_convertible_v<std::function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>()>&,
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ evaluates to false
> /usr/include/c++/11/optional:1002:20: error: no matching function for
> call to
> ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>()>&)’
> 1002 |             return static_cast<_Tp>(std::forward<_Up>(__u));
>       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
````

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Which line causes the error? What's the signature of `currentWeather`? What's the `std::function` signature that you're attempting to assign to? It sounds like those two signatures are different.

Comment: `std::function<std::string()>` requires a function that returns a `std::string`, but your lambda has no `return` statment at all

Comment: If the goal is to throw when accessing an empty optional, you can just use the `value()` method

Comment: @Wutz Yes, You're right. It was too late, that I didn't see such obvious problem :/ After adding `return std::string()` this line is fine but still there is a problem with that statement. 
`playlist->push_back(playlistSampler.getConstantElement(PlaylistSampler_ConstanElement::CURRENT_WEATHER).value_or(lazyFailsafe));` Related compile error is `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::function<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>()>&)’`

Comment: @Wutz. Yeap but my function prints something to the log file before throwing an exception. Although if I wouldn't be able to solve that issue a change would be made.

Comment: @alter_igel Please look at the edit on the top. I added link do my Github where this file is shared.

Comment: Your issue is that value_or expects something convertible to a string (the value type of the optional), not a function returning a string. So passing an std::function into it will not work. I guess you could create a custom struct with a cast-to-string operator, where said cast operator will log + throw if it gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're doing somewhat goes against the idea of how to use an optional. If you need to execute custom code when an empty optional is accessed, you should probably create a helper function.

However, it is possible. You tried to pass a functor returning a string into `value_or`. However, `value_or` expects a value that is implicitly convertible to a string, so the functor won't work.

In case you want to keep your approach, I came up with this:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Checker
{
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
        std::cout << "This gets executed when the optional is empty" << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error{"empty optional"}; // maybe throw bad_optional_access instead
    }
};
constexpr Checker checker{};

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> full = 1;
    std::cout << "Full optional: " << full.value_or(checker) << std::endl;

    std::optional<std::string> empty{};
    std::cout << "Empty optional: " << empty.value_or(checker) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Explanation: the type Checker is implicitly convertible to any other type using the templated conversion operator. Passing it to value_or passes a reference to checker, which only an empty std::optional will try to convert to its value type.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7xPPq8z8a)

Answer (score 1):

In your code line 108 `.value_or(lazyFailsafe)`. The `lazyFailsafe` object type is `std::function<std::string()>` and the related optional object type is `std::optional<std::string>`.

From std::optional::value_or description `template< class U > constexpr T value_or( U&& default_value )` and its one of type requirement is `U&& must be convertible to T`.

So there is no conversion allowed from `std::function<std::string()>` to `std::string`. You have to use `lazyFailsafe`'s call operator in `value_or()` call like this: `.value_or(lazyFailsafe())`.

Comment: This will make `lazyFailsafe` into an eager failsafe, executing even for optionals that contain a value.

Comment: Yes, but @Wutz just explained what is a problem here. A value of an `value_or` is evaluated regardless if optional contains something or not.